# JPA query: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The exception is thrown when I want to query for the youngest (by date) record by userId with userId not empty.. Is this method written correct or there is some error ?

I have following components:

**Repository**

```
public interface CustomEventStorage extends JpaRepository<CustomEventData, CustomEventDataId> {
    CustomEventData findFirstByUserIdNotNullOrderByIdDateDesc(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class CustomEventData {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomEventDataId id;

    @Column(name = "state")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EventState state;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
```

**Embedabble id**

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomEventDataId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private String eventId;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;
```

**Exception**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s)
>   provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$CriteriaQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:291)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createQueryParameterSetter$1(ParameterBinderFactory.java:139)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:141)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createSetters$0(ParameterBinderFactory.java:131)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:132)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:124)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createCriteriaBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:75)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.getBinder(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:250)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:149)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:270)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:79)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 70 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA didn't expect `userId` in query because you use `UserIdNotNull` which means `user_id IS NOT NULL` in query which don't expect `userId`. Use this way `userId`

```
CustomEventData findFirstByUserIdOrderByIdDateDesc(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

You don't need to check not null becasuse you are passing userId.